# How to get number in a bracket/ parentheses with R

Tags: r

I am confused on how to extract the number within the parentheses in a “character” vector with R

This is the case

```
Data <- c("182 (450)", "7,736,000 (19,120,000)", "350 (860)")
```

And this is the output that I am trying to look for,

```
>   450,     19120000,   860
```

I am still searching for possible function and approach for this type of problem. Any help and suggestion would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub`to extract everything between parentheses.

```
result <- sub('.*\\((.*)\\).*', '\\1', Data)
result
#[1] "450"        "19,120,000" "860"
```

Characters like (`()*&$`) have special meaning in regex so when we want to match them literally we need to escape them. Escaping is done by using `\\` in R. So here we first escape the opening parentheses (`\\(`), create a capture group (`(.*)`) to capture everything between opening parentheses and closing one (`\\)`) which we escape again. We use backreference `\\1` to return the expression captured in the capture group.

and same using `str_extract`

```
result <- stringr::str_extract(Data, "(?<=\\().*(?=\\))")
```

---

If you want to convert data to numeric use :

```
as.numeric(gsub(',', '', result))
#OR
#readr::parse_number(result)
#[1]      450 19120000      860
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
It seems I still do not know what the meaning of these symbols   

'.*\\((.*)\\).*', '\\1' 

Do you have any reference or topic in which I could learn these symbols definition/ mean

Comment: @FadelErwin I added some explanation in the answer you can start learning more about regular expressions here - https://www.regular-expressions.info/